# poetry run tox FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-poetry, tox

While running `poetry run tox` I encountered the vague error FileNotFoundError

```bash
poetry run tox                                                           1:38:03

  FileNotFoundError

  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/sbin\n\nsource /Users/willcasswrig/.poetry/env/tox'

  at /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py:607 in _execvpe
       603│         path_list = map(fsencode, path_list)
       604│     for dir in path_list:
       605│         fullname = path.join(dir, file)
       606│         try:
    →  607│             exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
       608│         except (FileNotFoundError, NotADirectoryError) as e:
       609│             last_exc = e
       610│         except OSError as e:
       611│             last_exc = e
```

Note: adding `-vvv` verbose flag didn't help

Related bug and error handling thread on GitHub: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `tox` was listed under the `[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]` section of my `pyproject.toml` file, it wasn't automatically added.

Either run `poetry add tox` or move from dev-dependencies section into `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`